# Where do we use "IT" in sentence? For person we use he/she in singular

Tags: grammar, present-continuous

"It" in which sentence it is used
For Tom we use he
For Niana we use she

Comment: https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/it

Answer (score 2):

Assuming Tom is a male human and Niana is a female human, you ***must*** use the pronouns ***he*** and ***she*** to refer to them (or gender-neutral "singular ***they***"). If they're dogs, "pet" fish, or whatever, you can optionally use ***it***.

Examples such as boats and (European) nations being treated as female are potentially misleading, because *most* native speakers don't do this today (it's dated / poetic).

But if you've given something a (gender-specific) name, (even if you just affectionately named your *car* "Emma") you'd often maintain the [anthropomorphism](https://psychcentral.com/health/why-do-we-anthropomorphize) by saying things like *She's being serviced by the local garage tomorrow*.

We nearly always use ***it*** for inanimate gender-neutral referents, as well as for non-human living things where the gender isn't contextually relevant.

Answer (score 1):

Use "He" for a male person.  Use "She" for a female person. Use "It" for one other thing.

> It is a book.

> I bought some rice.  It cost £5.

> Here's an apple.  Eat it.

> My car broke down.  I put some oil on it.

In these four cases, "it" is used for "a book",  "some rice", "an apple" and "My car".